# Dropdown SelectedItem.Value with a different text

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a dropdownlist with textm but i would like just use half of this phrase how can i do that easy? i will show my code, right now i just can get the full text.

i just want take the hours in the text: 1hr, 24hrs. i delete the text.

example:Text="Send reminder 1hr before"

so i want like that: Text="1hr"

i just want to take the hour , thanks guys

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="reminderOptions" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="Don't send reminder" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="3600" Text="Send reminder 1hr before" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="86400" Text="Send reminder 24hrs before" />
</asp:DropDownList>
lblReminderSet.Text = reminderOptions.SelectedItem.Value;
lblReminderSet.Text = String.Format("a message sent to you {0} your lessons", reminderOptions.SelectedItem.Text);
```

Comment: Am I missing something? After reading this I'm left wondering why you don't just edit the text attribute value

Comment: Why can't you just take the `Value` of the `ListItem`?!

Answer (score 5):

Let's say we use a Regex to pull that time frame out:

```
(\d+hr[s]?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KH0LyevInaAoUVjX)

This expression says find me any digit, one or more times, followed by `hr`, optionally followed by `s`. Now, to use this you might do something like this:

```
var match = Regex.Match(reminderOptions.SelectedItem.Text, @"(\d+hr[s]?)");
if (match.Success)
{
    var hrs = match.Groups[1];
    lblReminderSet.Text = string.Format(
        "a message sent to you {0} your lessons", hrs);
}
```

Now, if you also want the word `before` you can modify the Regex slightly:

```
(\d+hr[s]? before)
```

and grab that as part of the match.